# False Positives in String.contains and Regex.match C#

Tags: c#, string, full-text-search, contains

I am trying to find news articles with certain keywords in the headline but I am getting alot of false positives when using string.contains or Regex.match I am hoping someone can help point me in the direction to improve accuracy.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Basic code is simply.  the string in question

```
string baseHeadline = (string)newsRow["Headline"];
string headline = baseHeadline.ToLower();
bool isUpgrade = false
isUpgrade = headline.Contains("upgrade");
```

i am ok with it finding upgrade, upgrades, upgrade's as long as upgrade is there.

while this seems to find what I am looking for it is also generating alot of false positives as well.

- **Examples of false positives and true positives below.**

Examples of the Headlines that have produced false Positives.

> Stocks That Hit 52-Week Lows On Friday

> JMP Securities Reiterates Market Outperform on Capital Southwest, Maintains $22 Price Target

- **Examples of headlines that should trigger (True Positive)**

> Analyst Upgrades Arrowhead Pharma Citing 'Attractive Risk/Reward'

> Morgan Stanley Upgrades Confluent to Overweight, Raises Price Target to $30

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/auLrO8

Comment: You should pass an appropriate case insensitive `StringComparison` to `Contains` rather than converting the headline to lowercase for the contains. You can also do the same for regular expressions (pass the ignore case option). Either way, I do t think the problem you have alluded to is reproducible regardless. It goes against how I'm familiar with `Contains` working both in .NET Framework and .NET.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  even using isUpgrade = baseHeadline.Contains("upgrade",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); I still get the false positives.   clearly I have to be doing something wrong.   I am going to try it again in 4.x vs 6.0 i am using currently.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a fiddle on the site that Klaus used to demonstrate your problem (with hardcoded values for the inputs). Also update your question with the same code. We need to be able to reproduce it to help you. Does it make a difference if you use the invariant case insensitive option?

Comment: So the example you posted uses string.Contains where is the example that uses Regex.Match()

Comment: @KlausGütter, the fiddle you posted hard codes the value of base line.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response taking the kids to the park.   I’m can only duplicate it with data when i pull it from the DB I have.   Makes me wonder if the indexes are corrupt and somehow it’s causing a problem.  I blew it away before I left and started repopulation.  I’ll test tonight and post an update.  I appreciate the responses.

Comment: I have got absolutely no idea why but that fixed it.